# How to add random state in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am creating a random noise using `np.random.normal()`. I wanted to add random state in it.
I tried this:

```
R = np.random.RandomState(1989)

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
noise = R.normal(mu, sigma, [2, 2])
```

I also tried setting random state using `random` package:

```
import random

random.seed(32)
noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, [2, 2])
```

Then I also tried setting random seed with:

```
np.random.seed(34)
```

But nothing is working. Can anyone tell me how do I add random state in this noise, so that `np.random.normal` will give me the same result every time I run it.

NOTE: `mu` and `sigma` are mean and standard deviation resp.

Comment: What do you mean with "its not working"? It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Random state is not giving me the same result everytime I ran it. I want same result for that `noise`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confused of how the RandomState works:

```
import numpy as np
R = np.random.RandomState(1989)

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
noise = R.normal(mu, sigma, [2, 2])
```

Out:

```
array([[-0.02637181,  0.00853202],
       [ 0.0430007 ,  0.08950686]])
```

Ok, what if I now execute the following again:

```
noise = R.normal(mu, sigma, [2, 2])
```

Out:

```
array([[ 0.05569555,  0.04411228],
       [ 0.03753885, -0.01499474]])
```

Why is that different? Because you get a "random" result every time you execute the code. So what does RandomState do?

Well everyone who will execute your code with that RandomState will first get:

```
array([[-0.02637181,  0.00853202],
       [ 0.0430007 ,  0.08950686]])
```

and after that at the second execution:

```
array([[ 0.05569555,  0.04411228],
       [ 0.03753885, -0.01499474]])
```

If you indeed would like to get the exact same result multiple times, you have to "initialize" the RandomState again, like so:

```
R = np.random.RandomState(1989)
noise = R.normal(mu, sigma, [2, 2])
```

instead of only:

```
noise = R.normal(mu, sigma, [2, 2])
```

which is basically the "second execution of RandomState(1989)" and will therefore lead to different results.